# I want to search value from another datagridview to another datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

I can search value from textbox to data gridview but this time how can I search value from another datagridview to another datagridview and count how many times the value appeared and displaying the counting to another column.

Comment: What have you tried already?

Comment: i tried : for (int i =0; i Datagridview1.Rows.Count; i++)

Comment: See [how to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please add some code of what you have tried so far.